# Route errors when using namespace routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, namespaces, controller

How do you deal with `form_for`'s when the routes are namespaced? I am getting some weird route errors that I really expect to get.

For example, let's say you have a controller called `Admin::CompaniesController` in
your `:admin` namespace in your routes.rb:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :companies
end
```

Most things work just fine, but I get an error when I render a new form. Here's the code:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@company, :url => admin_company_path(@company)) do |f| %>
```

And here's the error message:

```
ActionView::Template::Error: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"admin/companies", :id=>#<Company id: nil, name: nil, phone_number: nil, address: nil, postal_code: nil, is_enabled: true, courses_created: 0, province_id: nil, theme_id: nil, payment_plan_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>}
```

How can I get rails to play nice here? I obviously want one url for edits, and another for new forms. Usually, I'd never even have to put `:url` in my `form_for` statements, but because of the nesting, I am forced to.

I have no idea what to do here now, at least not elegantly.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try using `simple_form_for([:admin, @company]) do |f|`

Comment: That is so much better than my solution above. Thank you. I'm glad rails had a nice way to do it.

Comment: Awesome, glad to see that it worked for you. Good luck with your app!

Comment: Awesome! Also had the same problem here, migrating from Rails 4.0.0 to 4.0.1, using simple_form 3.0.0. Thank you!

Comment: There's an edge case where this falls on its face: Using [friendly_id](http://rubygems.org/gems/friendly_id) with a scoped `slug`, and not scoping your admin URLs. For example `/locations/placename/photos/picturename` with an admin URL at `/admin/photos/picturename/edit`. This will cause friendly_id to search for the `photo` by the slug 'picturename', so if you have multiple `photos` with that slug it will just use the first one it finds.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I just have to pluralize the path at the end of the path, like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@company, :url => admin_companies_path(@company)) do |f| %>
```

This is not what I would have expected. I just guessed at it. This is not a valid route or anything, but it seems to work for puts and posts.

Comment: If you do it this way, you need to setup a different url if you're editing or creating a new entry - new entry would use admin_companies_path and an edit would use admin_company_path(@company), but the solution above is better all around because it works properly for both edit & new.